# Uglifying JavaScript - Further optimisation

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifier

This might seem like a stupid question but is there some reason why Uglifiers don't uglify references to external functions using a pointer?

An example:

A file I'm working on has multiple calls to `_gaq.push()`. I've squished this by adding to the top of the file `var _g=_gaq.push();`. I then update the 12 calls to it to use the `_g` pointer. This hasn't saved a huge amount (84 bytes) but every little helps right?

Am I missing something, is there a reason Uglifiers don't do this?

Comment: Some do. In the case of the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?hl=en), you can get an insane amount of reduction, which includes renaming variable names and references. This compiler makes use of most modern compiling techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, because there is too much potential for the code to break.

Assuming you mean `var _g=_gaq.push;`, then two possible causes of breakage spring to mind:

1. You've changed the value of `this` inside `push`. If the functionality of `push` depends on that, then you just broke it.
2. If the value of `_gaq.push` is changed *after* you assign it to `_g` then your code would continue to operate on the *old* value.

Comment: OK, so by doing this, I'm not creating a pointer, I'm creating copy.

Shame, a quick tally of all the similar places I could do this showed it could have made quite a difference,

Comment: You are creating a copy of the function reference, you aren't exactly cloning the function.

Comment: @AsciiSmoke Try `var a = []; var b = a.push; b(1); console.log(a);` It won't add `1` to `a`.